# i have 0.10096 mbtc (0.00010096 BTC) in my btc wallet but when ever i try to send bitcoins it always says your balance is low to pay the fee

Tags: wallet, transaction-fees

kindly tell me how much fee is charged over 0.1 mbtc as i have this much amount and i want to send it but it always shows this balance is too low to pay charges.

Comment: it doesn't matter how much BTC you transfer, the fee will be the same.. so it's not percentage like credit cards or so but a fixed amount probably higher than your balance. It is not really "fixed" to be honest but not a function of the transferred amount let me say.

Comment: depending what wallet you use. you might be able to control the fee. from local wallet I set the amount of fee I want to spend on transaction.

Comment: This is currently worth about $0.50 USD.   Is this an amount worth pursuing?  Do you have any other addresses / wallets that you may be able to combine?

Answer (score 1):

The fees you may pay for a transaction do not depend on the amount to be transferred, but to the transaction size. Transaction size highly depends on the number of inputs and outputs, as well as the type of those.

For example, a normal `Pay-to-PubKey-Hash (P2PKH)` transaction with a simple input, lets say with the exact amount you referred to (`0.00010096 BTC`), will pay less fees than a transaction with the same amount but 2+ inputs.

Can it be that you have such amount of bitcoins spread in really small amount transactions?

Answer (score -3):

In preferences you can choose payment urgent normal economy. The fee is bigger if urgent is selected.